# Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Buen Día,
Tengo una función de sweet alert:

```
function myIdNo() {
    swal("Ooops", "No existe!", "error");
}
```

Y en un if la ejecuto asi:

```
if ($sql === FALSE) {
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           myIdNo();
           </script>';
}
```

pero cuando doy a ejecutar la consulta me sale este error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myIdNo is not defined
>       at Load.php:2

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Dice que la función `myIdNo()` no existe en el archivo `Load.php`. ¿A qué archivo pertenece esa función? ¿Estás incluyendo ese archivo en `Load.php`?

Comment: Tienes un paréntesis de más en tu **if**

Comment: Si la estoy incluyendo.

Comment: podrias mostrar como incluyes el codigo donde esta tu funcion

Answer (score 1):

Hola te recomiendo hagas lo siguiente:

Usa el signo de admiración que cierra al inicio de tu variable, ya que si es esta de tipo booleano basta con añadirlo para indicar que la estas negando

```
if(!$sql) {
     echo "<script>
            myIdNo();
           </script>"
}
```

También es importante mencionar que si estas trabajando con PHP como se asume por la etiqueta de la preguntam a tu variable le hace falta el signo de pesos al inicio saludos

Comment: Si la puse mal pero ese no es el error

Answer (score -1):

Deberias tener tu condicional de esta manera;

```
if (sql === FALSE) {
     echo '<script type="text/javascript"> myIdNo();</script>';
}
```

no como lo tienes;

```
if (sql) === FALSE) {
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           myIdNo();
           </script>';
}
```

En primer lugar tu `if` tiene un parentesis sobrante justo despues de la "variable" `sql` y la cadena de tu `echo` deberia estar en 1 linea.

En base a que el ejemplo anterior no funciono te comento algo que hice en base a tu problema, declara la funcion antes de la salia del codigo, te pongo un ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myIdNo(){};
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<?= 
$sql = true;
if ($sql) {
     echo '<script type="text/javascript"> myIdNo();</script>';
}
 ?>
</html>
```

Al final el error es porque la variable no ha sido declarada y por esto la consola te arroja el error que mencionas;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Yo. Si el problema de la pregunta es debido a errores tipograficos, no deberian responderse si no comentarle qué fallo tiene y reportarla para su cierre. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b De acuerdo, gracias!

Comment: No pero ese no es el error.

Comment: @Kygo coloca en 1 linea el echo y prueba, vuelves aca y nos indicas.

Comment: No sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: @Kygo agrege mas información, verificarla y me indicas.